# Injecting singletons in to a Spring Boot Application Context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, parent-child, applicationcontext

I want to inject some non-Spring managed beans in to a Spring Boot Application. I would have thought the way to do this would be something like:

```
    GenericApplicationContext parentContext = new StaticApplicationContext();
    parentContext.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("pipeline", pipeline);
    parentContext.refresh();   // seems to be required sometimes

    ApplicationContext context = new SpringApplicationBuilder()
            .sources(parentContext)
            .child(DispatcherApplication.class)
            .run();
```

However you can only pass in `Class<?>...` or `Object...` to the `sources` method on the builder and in the latter case the only values it recognises are:

- Class - A Java class to be loaded by AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader
- Resource - An XML resource to be loaded by XmlBeanDefinitionReader, or a groovy script to be loaded by GroovyBeanDefinitionReader
- Package - A Java package to be scanned by ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner
- CharSequence - A class name, resource handle or package name to loaded as appropriate.

So how do I either pass in a parent context instance, or inject singletons in to a Spring Boot application before startup?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create application with your modified context using Application Builder.

Simply make sure you Autowire **parentContext** and register singleton on the factory derived from it

Comment: Sorry not sure I'm entirely following can you expand on your answer a bit please?

Answer (score 0):

i couldn't get your parent context approach to work, for more or less the same reason you stated. instead, i:

- annotate the bean with `@Lazy` and `@Autowired`
- create an anonymous `ApplicationListener`
- in the listener call `getBeanFactory().registerSingleton()`
- add the listener to the app with `setListener()`

here's the stripped-down listener:

```
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof ContextRefreshedEvent) {
            ((GenericApplicationContext) (((ContextRefreshedEvent) event)
                    .getApplicationContext()))
                    .getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("legacyBean", obj);
        }
    }
```

i didn't find too much documentation on the application lifecycle, but at least most of what i'm doing is standard. however, it does rely on a cast of the context to `GenericApplicationContext` which "works for me" (Spring Boot 1.4.1) and seems safe, but in theory could change in future versions

my blog post with full source:
http://blog.nqzero.com/2018/01/integrating-spring-with-legacy-app.html